# Do I need to replace primitives in signatures with types?

Tags: typescript

I see one thing, it looks right, but it brings complexity, look..

I have an interface:

`interface Products { getProduct(id: string): Promise<Product>; }`

In other places, I may have classes with these primitive types too:

`class Product { public id: string; }`

So in case if id type will change, become not a string, but an object, or just number, then I have to change signature and fix calls in every place in my app.

But... If I will replace "string" with new `type UserId = string`, and then use it like `class Product { public id: UserId; }` and `getProduct(id: UserId): Promise<Product>;` then I will avoid all such changes, right?

Nope, it is not right, because I will be having to change code all over the app in this case too (as is interface change will not change the source code where I work with this variables).

So at one hand (if we do such types):

+ We do not need to change interface all over the app

- We still have to change our code all over the app

- Greatly reduced understandability (you have to know all types, instead of looking at primitives)

And if we do not write such types:

+ Simple to understand (primitives are readable)

- We still have to change our code all over the app

- We must change all signatures ourselves

What do you think, what is better?

Comment: How often do you actually write `const id: number = user.id` versus `const id = user.id`?

Comment: It is different, we are talking about classes and functions signatures.

Comment: I was referring to the statement "as is interface change will not change the source code where I work with this variables"